# php clean up rich textarea to display clean string

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm trying to clean up a string from a rich textarea. The string is something like:

```
<p> HI there </p>
```

The problem is when i use preg_rplace to romove  i get an output like:

```
p Hi there p
```

Anyone knows how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it was made for you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know that function. Thank you. Will accept answer in 4 min